# Confused with histogram plotting in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, histogram

Hello I'm trying to plot a histogram in Python. 
The y-axis needs to go up to values of 1e+19 and the x axis need to be from 0 to 10. I'm confused because I'm not sure how python is plotting this. I think it's graphing my y-axis data matrix on the x-axis.

```
flux_norm= (np.multiply(n,flux))
plt.hist(flux_norm, bins=30)
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10**19)
plt.title("Histogram of Normalized Flux")
plt.xlabel("Energy (MeV)")
plt.ylabel("Normalized flux")
```

The code above gives me a blank graph

```
flux_norm= (np.multiply(n,flux))
plt.hist(flux_norm, bins=30)
plt.title("Histogram of Normalized Flux")
plt.xlabel("Energy (MeV)")
plt.ylabel("Normalized flux")
```

The code above gives me a graph but only sets my y-axis to 2! and my x-axis is at 1e+19

Ive looked at the general ways to graph histograms on python but I can't find an example that's similar to my case. 
please send help

Answer (score 0):

You second code should work just fine, this outputs the following histogram:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


flux = np.arange(1,10**19,10**17)
n = np.arange(0,100,1)
flux_norm= (np.multiply(n,flux))
plt.hist(flux_norm, bins = 30)
##plt.xlim(0,10)
##plt.ylim(0,10**19)
plt.title("Histogram of Normalized Flux")
plt.xlabel("Energy (MeV)")
plt.ylabel("Normalized flux")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Aguiar I see, but it's not that I'm having a problem with having a high number of points to graph, it's that my flux matrix is a 7 element array, with each element with a value of magnitude of around 1e+19. Do you know how to graph that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You only have 7 elements in you entire data? I'm afraid that's too few to be represented in a histogram. First of all, try letting `matplotlib` to choose the bins, by deleting  `, bins = 30` in `plt.hist(flux_norm, bins = 30)`, and then let us know what happened.

Comment: Aguiar okay that makes a little more sense I guess I was just not getting the concept of a histogram lol. but yeah only 7 elements but teacher wants a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, in the first case there are no data plotted in the visible range of

```
plt.xlim(0,10)
plt.ylim(0,10**19)
```

Here is how first argument `x` in `hist` works - from [matplotlib.pyplot docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist)

> **x** : (n,) array or sequence of (n,) arrays
>
> Input values, this takes either a single array or a sequency of arrays
>   which are not required to be of the same length

Comment: Since this is a histogram, it's quite unusual to have no value at all in `ylim(0,10**19)`, my guess is that the data is not that large and then setting a really high superior limit  for `y` it's impossible to see the actual histogram without zooming in.

Comment: @matusko so how would one specify y values?

Comment: @Katey a histogram doesn't work like that, a [histogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) will always show frequency of data in y-axis.